# How to merge two email boxes securely with an email box fetcher?

Tags: passwords, email

I have two email boxes: The first one is my main email box in *Gmail* and the second one is in my website hosting company by *Thunderbird* which I access from my website hosting manager (**WHM**) which is *Cpanel*.

To prevent myself of checking both my email boxes each time anew non automatically I contemplate using a Gmail fetcher which allows me to somewhat merge the two email boxes and get all Thunderbird emails in Gmail (and if I understood correctly, to also reply to merged emails directly from Gmail but **as if** the reply is being done from Thunderbird).

How to merge two email boxes securely with an email box fetcher? When merging two email boxes, are there any best practice actions to take before or whilst doing so?
One thing I can think about is ensuring that the WHM-client password (Cpanel password) and the WHM-email-client password (Thunderbird password) would be very different, but are there more principles to take into account?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get everything in GMail, the feature already exists in Settings/Accounts And Imports.
You can retrieve your mail from your other account there, and set it up so replying to mail from your external provider has the external provider address, and not your Gmail one.

One thing, the recipient will still be able to see that the mail comes from Gmail.

Comment: Good answer, +1.  OP, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/250030/do-email-providers-somehow-validate-control-send-email-as-feature for some important nuances to be aware of, with regard to `setting it up so replying to mail from your external provider has the external provider address`.

Comment: Romain Prévost yes that's what I meant by "Gmail fetcher" but I thought that the (reply) recipient would not get my Gmail address (i.e. I thought that via the fetcher, Gmail would log in into my Thunderbird account and will send the reply from there).